# Refactor suggestion for C# try catch with server async Task return

Tags: c#, refactoring, try-catch, task

#### About the method

1. It is supposed to post data to the server side when session is valid.
2. [Check Session Locally] - [Refresh] - [Send Data]
3. [if 401 happens] - [Refresh] - [Send Data]

#### I'm not sure about

1. If there is any redundancy in the "IF" condition and "try-catch" block, that could be simplified.
2. Also, not familiar with the Task and async stuff, is the way that put the "PendRefresh" task inside correct or appropriate?

Appreciated for any suggestion!

```
private async Task<TResult> PostRequestAsync<TResult>(ServerRequest request)
{
    //check if expired on client side
    if (LocalHelper.IsExpired(request))
    {
        request.Token = await PendRefresh().ConfigureAwait(false);      //[Refresh]
    }

    try
    {
        return await PostServerAsync<TResult>(request).ConfigureAwait(false);   //[Send Data]
    }
    catch (ServerException e)
    {
        //session expired on the server side
        if (e.Code == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            request.Token = await PendRefresh().ConfigureAwait(false);              //[Refresh]
            return await PostServerAsync<TResult>(request).ConfigureAwait(false);   //[Send Data]
        }
    }
    return default;

    //Q2, is this OK?
    async Task<string> PendRefresh()
        {
        //something here
    }
}
```

#### Edit:

added a simple flow there

[image: simple img]

Comment: Does your code work? Just curious if you need help with an error, or you are only looking for reflector suggestions.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Yes, it works, I'm just looking for suggestions.

Comment: Actually, I refactored a bit before posting. Previous logic is [Send Data] - [Check 401] || [Check locally] - [Refresh] - [Send Data], which makes [Check locally] no sense when expired. Just a bit annoyed with the repetition now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have now is at least very readable.

You are repeating yourself a bit with the "refresh" and "send data" but given that I can see all of the workflow and failure points in one screen, I value that more than a more generic approach.

The only reason I would change this is if the refresh or send data functions became non-trivial and interfered with understanding the authentication workflow.

If you do want to re-architect this as an exercise, I think the technique you're looking for is a "[continuation task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks)".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, especially the link is wonderful for me to learn. And your "authentication workflow" means the method PendRefresh or CheckExpired or others?

Comment: a simple flow on the post added, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Correct; it looks to me like you're checking an authentication token for expiration, and refreshing if necessary, a completely normal workflow. I encourage you to do your best to create easily and maintainable code rather than "perfectly crafted" methods which meet all SOLID principals. In real life, being able to understand code, either your own from the past or code you didn't write, is what is most important.

Comment: Finally, I just moved the "token check" things out of this method, check it before calling the post and made PostRequestAsync simple. I also added a check when the token is about to expire, so as to avoid 401 from server side. Anyway, I also found some JWT auth flow could be my samples to learn, thx.